# setting deafult Printer details instead of using UIPrintInteractionController

Tags: iphone, airprint

Is there a way by which we can set default printer and its default size instead of using uiprintInterctionController ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no easy way to get around the UIPrintInteractionController, since it's ["the central class for printing in iOS"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPrintInteractionController_Class/index.html) (according to the first paragraph or two of the documentation).

Looking through that documentation, I did find a handy method called:

[`- printToPrinter:completionHandler:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPrintInteractionController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPrintInteractionController/printToPrinter:completionHandler:)

which allows you to print directly to the printer (presumably a previously selected printer from UIPrintInteractionController) without bringing up an interactive user interface.  It still brings up a printing progress dialog, though.